# ember js: can i use strings as ids for records

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

my rest api server returns strings as id for each resource.
it cannot use numbers and there is a chance that ids information might be lost while converting integer from server to number(float) in java script.
And there are other performance issues on the server side.

so can i use strings as ids for records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, in fact Ember Data's `RESTAdapter` coerces all ids into strings (This isn't true of the FixtureAdapter).

Comment: yes, currently it is coercing in to string before building/finding a record.